# SQL SUMs in where clause with conditionals

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, subquery

I want to get a "totals" report for business XYZ. They want the season,term,distinct count of employees, and total employee's dropped hours, only when dropped hours of anemployee != any adds that equal the drops.

trying to do something like this:

```
select year,
   season,
   (select count(distinct empID)
  from tableA
 where a.season = season
   and a.year = year) "Employees",
   (select sum(hours)
   from(
     select distinct year,season,empID,hours
       from tableA
              where code like 'Drop%'
    )
  where a.season = season
    and a.year = year) "Dropped"

from tableA a
-- need help below
where (select sum(hours)
   from(
     select distinct year,season,empID,hours
       from tableA
      where code like 'Drop%'
    )
   where a.season = season
     and a.year = year
     and a.emplID = emplID)
!=
 (select sum(hours)
   from(
     select distinct year,season,empID,hours
       from tableA
      where code like 'Add%'
    )
   where a.season = season
     and a.year = year
     and a.emplID = emplID)
  group by year,season
```

It appears I am not correctly doing my where clause correctly. I dont believe I am joining the emplID to each emplID correctly to exlude those whos "drops" <> "adds"

EDIT:
sample data:
year,season,EmplID,hours,code
2015, FALL, 001,10,Drop
20150 FALL, 001,10,Add
2015,FALL,002,5,Drop
2015,FALL,003,10,Drop

The total hours should be 15. EmplyID 001 should be removed from the totaling because he has drops that are exactly equal to adds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out with a bit of analytics .. ;)

```
  with tableA as ( 
           select 2015 year, 1 season, 1234 empID, 2 hours  , 'Add' code from dual union all
           select 2015 year, 1 season, 1234 empID, 3 hours  , 'Add' code from dual union all
           select 2015 year, 1 season, 1234 empID, 4 hours  , 'Add' code from dual union all
           select 2015 year, 1 season, 1234 empID, 2 hours  , 'Drop' code from dual union all
           select 2015 year, 1 season, 2345 empID, 5 hours  , 'Add' code from dual union all
           select 2015 year, 1 season, 2345 empID, 3.5 hours, 'Add' code from dual union all
           select 2015 year, 2 season, 1234 empID, 7 hours  , 'Add' code from dual union all
           select 2015 year, 2 season, 1234 empID, 5 hours  , 'Add' code from dual union all
           select 2015 year, 2 season, 2345 empID, 5 hours  , 'Add' code from dual union all
           select 2015 year, 2 season, 7890 empID, 3 hours  , 'Add' code from dual union all
           select 2014 year, 1 season, 1234 empID, 1 hours  , 'Add' code from dual union all
           select 2014 year, 1 season, 1234 empID, 2 hours  , 'Add' code from dual union all
           select 2014 year, 1 season, 1234 empID, 4 hours  , 'Add' code from dual
        ),
     w_group as (     
        select year, season, empID, hours, code,
               lead(hours) over (partition by year, season, empID, hours 
                             order by case when code like 'Drop%' then 'DROP'
                                           when code like 'Add%' then 'ADD'
                                           else NULL end ) new_hours
          from tableA
        )
  select year, season, count(distinct empID),
              sum(hours-nvl(new_hours,0)) total_hours
    from w_group
   where code like 'Add%'
   group by year, season
  /

        YEAR     SEASON COUNT(DISTINCTEMPID) TOTAL_HOURS
  ---------- ---------- -------------------- -----------
        2015          1                    2        15.5
        2014          1                    1           7
        2015          2                    3          20
```

(the first part "with tableA" is just faking some data, since you didn't provide any) :)

[edit]
corrected based on your data, and your explanation - in short, you're counting the DROPs, (minus the ADDs), I was doing the reverse
[edit2] replaced below query with minor tweak based on comment/feedback: don't count an empID if their DROP-ADD zero out)

```
 with tableA as ( 
     select 2015 year, 'FALL' season, '001' empID, 10 hours, 'Drop' code from dual union all
     select 2015 year, 'FALL' season, '001' empID, 10 hours, 'Add' code from dual union all
     select 2015 year, 'FALL' season, '002' empID, 5  hours, 'Drop' code from dual union all
     select 2015 year, 'FALL' season, '003' empID, 10 hours, 'Drop' code from dual
       ),
    w_group as (     
       select year, season, empID, hours, code,
              lag(hours) over (partition by year, season, empID, hours 
                            order by case when code like 'Drop%' then 'DROP'
                                          when code like 'Add%' then 'ADD'
                                          else NULL end ) new_hours
         from tableA
       )
 select year, season, count(distinct empID),
             sum(hours-nvl(new_hours,0)) total_hours
   from w_group
  where code like 'Drop%'
    and hours - nvl(new_hours,0) > 0
  group by year, season
 /

        YEAR SEAS COUNT(DISTINCTEMPID) TOTAL_HOURS
  ---------- ---- -------------------- -----------
        2015 FALL                    2          15
```

[/edit]

Comment: i dont think this is what I want... i added sample data above

Comment: ahh, I see ... just need to reverse the logic. I was adding the "ADDs", minus the "DROPs" .. seems you want the reverse. So use LAG, not lead, then keep the DROPs, instead of the ADDs at the end .. viola .. 15.

Comment: almost this! the total count for emplID should be 2. If an employee has adds = drops, exclude them from all counts

Comment: No worries, replaced the query above with the changes: add a condition to where clause, to only include those with hours left after DROP - ADD is done.

Comment: thank you. I am trying to understand this process, what is 'over' doing? is there a way to do this without using 'over?

Comment: lag looks at the next row. over is just part and parcel with lag function, to indicate analytics (there are other analytics functions, search them and read up .. they are very useful), what follows it is of more interest. partition by is just like "group by" really, it indicates how to organize the data, so the lag won't look at the next row, if the next row is not part of the same group/partition.  (run the query in steps to see what's it doing - that is just query from w_group and see what things look like prior to that final query)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with just conditional aggregation.  Something like this:

```
select year, season, count(distinct empID) as Employees,
       sum(case when code like 'Drop%' then hours end) as Dropped
from tableA
group by year, season;
```

It is hard to tell exactly what you want, because you do not have sample data and desired results (or better yet, a SQL Fiddle).  You might also want a `having` clause:

```
having (sum(case when code like 'Drop%' then hours end) <>
        sum(case when code like 'Add%' then hours end) 
       )
```

Comment: added sample data and a bit of an exaplnation

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting the result of something like this?

```
SELECT
   year
   ,season
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT empID) AS Employees
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN code LIKE 'Drop%' THEN hours ELSE 0 END) AS Dropped
FROM
   TableA
GROUP BY
   year
   ,season
HAVING
   (
   SUM(CASE WHEN code LIKE 'Drop%' THEN hours ELSE 0 END) 
   - SUM(CASE WHEN code LIKE 'Add%' THEN hours ELSE 0 END)
   ) <> 0
```

Comment: something like this yes, but it is not quite working yet... my sum in the select uses a distinct subqeury to get the correct results.